# Find all multiples of 3 or 5 but not 15 using python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to find the multiples of 3 and 5 but not 15, in python
by using list comprehension,

```
list = []

a = [a for a in range(1,100) if ((a % 3 == 0) and (a % 5 == 0))]
list.append(a)
print(a)
```

the logic is wrong

Comment: a = [a for a in range(1,100) if ((a % 3 == 0) and (a % 5 == 0) and (a%15 !=0))]
list.append(a)
print(a) --This returns a empty list

Comment: I got the mistake guys - a = [a for a in range(1,100) if ((a % 3 == 0) or (a % 5 == 0)) and (a%15 !=0)] - it should be this----------Closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

multiples = [num for num in range(1, 100) if ((num % 3 == 0) or (num % 5 == 0)) and (num % 15 != 0)]
print(multiples)